# Is there is any way to detect if the user removed any item from localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, web

i am developing a web app using reactJS and i am using local storage to store temporary data and i want to log the user out if any of these data was removed from the local storage.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nasser! This question is very broad, so it will be hard for someone to help you. Please include the code you have written so far and read  [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well to check if _any_ of it was removed, you would have to first of all know what “all of it” was to begin with - and where would you want to store _that_ info …?

Comment: In practice, you only fetch data from local storage when your app loads. Then you use stores to keep your data. Since stores cannot be altered by user directly there won't be a chance of user manipulating the data. This way you can apply a check at the beginning.

Comment: @Fawaz Of course the user can modify the local storage even with simple built-in tools like e.g. chrome developer toolbar. I think this is not about preventing manipulation. But probably a correct error handling should make this superfluous.

Comment: @trixn by stores I'm referring to reducers, my bad.

Comment: @Fawaz Reducers (if you are referring to redux reducers) can also be manipulated like everything can be manipulated in client side javascript code. Security and permission relevant data always have to be validated at server side. Everything else does not need to be protected against vandalism. Who cares if a user breaks his own side of the application on purpose. OP did not give a use case for his requirement but to me it sounds like some kind of "graceful shutdown".

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

> **Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent**
>
> The [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) is fired whenever a change is made to the
>   Storage object (note that this event is not fired for sessionStorage
>   changes). This won't work on the same page that is making the changes
>   — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage
>   to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access
>   the same storage objects.

On the events page [(see events.js)](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/web-storage/event.js) the only JavaScript is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
  .....
});
```

Comment: @NasserAlhatlan please accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

When the local storage changes a [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) will be fired. You can listen to that event:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
    // handle change
});
```

But you can not ultimately prevent users from manipulating the local storage. This can only be a convenience action but is not able to increase security.